# Why is Logstash not excluding it's own log file?

Tags: logstash

According to the logstash docs, this should work; but logstash keeps causing a recursion by logging it's own stdout log to itself...

What is incorrect about my exclude config?

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/var/log/**/*"
        exclude => ["**/*.gz", "logstash/*"]

    }
}

output {
    tcp {
        host => "1.2.3.4"
        port => 1234
        mode => client
        codec => json_lines
    }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

I see results with the path set to /var/log/logstash/logstash.stdout when it should be ignoring them.

(I've tested this by completely deleting the logs in the /var/log/logstash dir and restarting)

I've tried these in the array for exclusion:

```
logstash/*
**/logstash/*
/var/log/logstash/* #This is incorrect according to docs
```

Comment: Since the exclusion globs are matched against the filename, wouldn't logstash.* be the correct pattern to use? (For that reason I'd say all your exclusion patterns are invalid.)

Comment: True. I finally re-read the docs and took the "filename" part literally. If you want to post this as an answer I'll + it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exclusion patterns for Logstash's [file input](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/inputs/file) are, as documented, matched against the bare filename of encountered files, so the three patterns in the question won't ever match anything. To exclude Logstash log files and gzipped files use `logstash.*` and `*.gz` as exclusion patterns.